# How do I connect a SQL Server synonym to an Excel data model?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, sql-server-2012

I have a SQL Server (12.0.411) database with a view that is referenced by a synonym.

I want to load the data from the view into Excel's data model using the synonym.

In Excel (Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013) I go Data/Connections/Add to Data Model. The Select Table dialog offers my the views and the synonyms but when I select a synonym I get an error box:

We can't find table "DBName"."dbo"."synonymname".

Is this a known limitation or am I missing something?

If I don't add to the Data Model, but simply put the data into a table in Excel it all woks as expected, so I don't believe the problem is with permissions.